# 入門書通りコードを書き、pyファイルをターミナル上で実行したところエラーが出ました。

Tags: python, python3

タイトルにある通り、エラーが出ます。
コード、エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

【コード】

```
import random

class Dice:
    face_num=6
    def _init_(self):

        print("Hello")

def shoot(self):
        return random.randint(1,self.face_num)
```

【エラーメッセージ】

> ```
> >>> import dice
> >>> sai=dice.Dice()
> >>> sai.shoot()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'Dice' object has no attribute 'shoot'
> ```

---

問題⑴
sai=dice.Dice()の部分でHelloが出ません。

問題⑵
sai.shoot()の部分でランダムに１〜６の数字が出ません。
＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿

当方初学者であり、大変初歩的な質問であるとは自覚しておりますが、
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `__init__`の両側は _ が2つずつです。一つだけだと、ただのメソッドになってしまいます。
2. `def shoot(self):` がインデントされていないので、Dice クラスとは関係のない関数になっています。Python ではインデントがとても重要なので気を付けてください。

手直ししたコードは

```
import random

class Dice:
    face_num=6
    def __init__(self):

        print("Hello")

    def shoot(self):
        return random.randint(1,self.face_num)
```

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。解説までしていただき恐縮です。
無事に実行することができました。感謝です。